# How do I stack a minecart on a bat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to make an invincible minecart on an invincible bat? Is it possible to make it controllable? How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylGgYRwH-LM

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not in the AI of the bats to have "driveable" controls, so no, it can't be "driven".

But this command should work:

```
/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat"}}
```

As for making it invincible, I'm not *entirely* sure if this will work (won't be able to test it until I get home)

```
/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:"Bat",Invulnerable:1},Invulnerable:1}
```

Comment: As for moving the bat: You could try command blocks (using `/entitydata`) that gives `NoAI:true` to bats when the minecart is ridden, then revert to `NoAI:false` when the player hops off. As for moving, while the player is in the minecart, teleport the bat [forward relative to the direction the player is looking at] while it has the `NoAI:true` NBT tag. **But that's too repeatitive and long-winded to write into the answer anyways..**

Answer (score -2):

/summon MinecartRideable ~ ~1 ~ {Riding:{id:Bat,Riding:{id:Pig}}} should probably work for steering? (might need an extra }

Comment: No, this won't work, at least not in the way the OP presumably wants it to work.